# iOS How to find which Shortcut is "running in background"

Tags: iphone, ios

This just started happening after creating a 'link to open in safari' and working with others to see if there was anyway to auto "Add to Home".

Now Under Battery Settings, I see it says Shortcuts is running in background, but how do I find which Shortcut is running.

I have tried force closing Shortcuts, and rebooting. I've tried disabling the new Shortcuts ShareSheets.

[image]